# ASP.NET Identity - Filter roles based on company

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I have a web application that holds data for multiple companies (like Multitenancy) but a user can have access to more than one company (point of difference from Multitenancy). Furthermore, a user may have different access rights for different companies.

For Example: 
User A has Admin access for Company A and only Basic access for Company B

To support this functionality I have added Company to the `AspNetUserRoles` table. What I want to do is filter the roles returned by Identity framework based on the Company selected for the user logging in.

The application uses `FindByNameAsync` method from the `UserManager` class to return the user object but I assume my tie in point is further back in the stack.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality and where is the best tie in point?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by:

1. Adding multiple roles for one company for e.g. CompanyA_Admin, CompanyA_Basic, CompanyB_Admin, CompanyB_Basic in aspnet_Roles table
2. Then further get all roles for a given user by        System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()
3. To get all the companies for the user:

   ```
   string[] CompaniesForUser()
   {

   //Change to commented version for production   
   string[] roles = new string[] { "CompanyA_Admin", "CompanyB_Admin", "CompanyA_Basic", "CompanyB_Basic" };  //System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();
   string[] companies = new string[100];
   int index = 0;

   foreach(string role in roles)
   {
       string cName =  role.Split('_')[0];

       //Only add new companies
       if (!companies.Contains(cName))
       {
           companies[index] = cName;

           //Testing
           Response.Write("Index : " + index + " - " + cName + "<br>");

           index++;
       }
   }

   return companies;
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my preference is to not have duplicate roles for each company because then I would have to authorize all duplicate roles in the code. Furthermore, if a new company is added, I would have to traverse all the code and update to include roles for the new company.